# how to include image in an email send from android app?

Tags: android, image, email

I need to include an image in the email which is send from my app. I have written the code to include text and it is working fine.but I don't know how to include image.my image resides in the drawable folder.how can I include that?
NB:I have gone through many posts but nothing helped me..

edit:

my current code is given below

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body,new ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawFromPath;
        //  int path = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", "com.package...");
        drawFromPath = (Drawable) getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawFromPath;
    }
}, null));
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an image by setting the following two values:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("directory's path", "filename"));

intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: i need to send text also.if i change the type will it affect that?

Comment: then try setting it to **"text/html"**, but first try sending with image/jpeg

Comment: i want to take image from drawable folder not from file.how can i do that?

Comment: I think you can do it by saving that image from **drawable** to a temporary location on SDcard as an image and then use that image's path in the attachment